# Can i use outlook without having a .ost file at all?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, regedit

Im in a bit of a pickle. At my office we are working with about 100-150 computers. At the moment all of them are using cached exchange mode and creating a local .ost file when logging in on a new computer.

However there are a few guest/shared computers which we want to not create a local .ost file on them when loging in and opening outlook. Is there a way to prevent outlook from creating an .ost file and going directly to online mode? Perhaps in windows regestry? regedit

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Cached Exchange Mode in Outlook settings:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP010355560.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have is that registry is per user (e.g. current_user) so it will need to be done after the user logs in and creates the outlook profile unless this is created on logon?

My advice would be to use Group Policy and the Office ADMX where you will find the setting under:

User Configuration | Policies | Administrative Templates | Microsoft Outlook 2010 | Account Settings | Exchange | Cached Exchange Mode | Use Cached Exchange Mode for new and Existing Outlook Profiles

Again its a User Configuration so you will have to also configure loopback option to loop it from a user configuration to a computer setting to affect all users.

Then set the GPO to a separate OU for those machines (if they are part of the domain this is)...